How to list changes after Merge Request was merged?
I'm building a Gitlab CI/CD. I’m facing an issue determining which projects to deploy/destroy after a Merge Request is merged into the “main” branch of our monorepo. The goal is to trigger pipelines only for projects with actual changes in the Merge Request.
Our monorepo contains multiple independent projects within a “projects” folder. Importantly, only one team member works on a specific project at a time.
I’ve managed to successfully identify changed projects during the Merge Request pipeline, when a Merge Request is opened, using:
- git fetch
- changes=$(git diff --name-status origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME origin/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -- projects/)

This first pipeline allows to run some tests and ensure the changed projects are valid.
However, I’m struggling to replicate this logic for the pipeline triggered after the Merge Request is merged. Indeed the second pipeline is no longer a Merge Request pipeline but a branch pipeline so I can’t simply run the same “git diff” command. I need to retrieve the exact same changes to actually deploy/destroy these changed projects.
I’ve considered two potential solutions:

Comparing commits: Determine the relevant commits from the Merge Request and compare them to the “main” branch. This approach seems complex due to potential squashing and multiple concurrent Merge Requests.
Using artifacts: Store the changed projects in an artifact during the Merge Request pipeline. Retrieving and using this artifact in the subsequent pipeline is challenging due to potential naming conflicts and overall complexity.

Is there a more efficient way to identify changed projects after a Merge Request is merged?
